How can I fix the issue where the open BFE filter with views Contextual filters?
I have a view page that displays based on the context of the taxonomy term name, whose path is/category/network/%.

Example page: /category/network/ethernet, where "ethernet" is the context Taxonomy term name.
I am displaying an open BFE filter with a network selection. This filter works on the previous levels of the URL, such as /category/network or /category/. But it does not work when the open page has the URL /category/network/ethernet.
BFE creates a URL like: /network/ethernet?field_network_rel_target_id%5B1372%5D=1372 because the term name is already set in the URL.
Using AJAX does not help. Can anyone suggest how to solve this?
I found that the Views Filter Harmonizer module does this, but only for Drupal 7. Here's the quote:

Since the contextual filter sets the "bounds" for the page, any filtering by the visitor through the exposed filter on that page can only narrow down the results set, not broaden it. In other words the exposed filter appears not to be working properly.


I don't know if this can be achieved without a module. In theory it sounds logical that for a contextual filter we should specify that it should only work if we don't have any URL parameters set. But maybe the problem is that the context will override the exposed filter anyway.

You are mis-understanding contextual filters. A contextual filter is a hard, pre-set filter, not an user-exposed filter and not an URL-beautifier. Maybe https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pretty_paths is more your use-case?

Thanks. But I think if I use the Exposable filter instead of the context, I won't be able to override the title.

I came up with an idea to display links instead of the exposed filter in Views as a header or attachment. However, it looks less dynamic than what the exposed filter offers
